# How to write text-align right in Markdown?

Tags: markdown, right-to-left, text-align

It's possible write text-align right in Markdown files?

For example write utf8 in Markdown files.

Comment: `utf-8` has nothing to do with text-alignment. Are you asking about Unicode right-to-left text direction? If so, that's also not the same thing as text-alignment either.

Answer (score 1):

By "md file" I assume you're referring to Markdown.

By "text-align: right" you could be referring to either the right-alignment of left-to-right text or referring to right-to-left writing order - which are orthogonal concerns.

- right-alignment of left-to-right writing:

  - Simply set `style="text-align: right;"` on any parent block-level elements (e.g. `<div>`, `<p>`, etc) or set a CSS rule (Your Markdown implementation should support inline `style=""` attributes, as well as `<style>` elements - check your implementation's documentation)
- right-to-left writing:

  - This is controlled by putting [a Unicode Right-to-left control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark) in your text. Provided you save the file in a Unicode encoding (e.g. `utf-8`, `utf-16`, etc) (and assuming your Markdown implementation doesn't remove the character) then compliant browsers will render the text in right-to-left order. This detail is fully independent of Markdown and works fine in other file formats too, including plaintext (e.g. in Windows Notepad), word-processors, and plain ol' HTML.